# How to provide ctrl+C in the shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the script that i tried to execute/automate testing,

```
 while [ 1 ]; do
 val=`expr $val + 1`
 ksh ./run.ksh   //This line needs the keyboard interaction so i can't run in background. It takes too long time to complete so i need to kill the above command using ctrl+C 
 echo "pid=$!"
 echo "pid=$$"
 sleep 40
 val1=val;
 done;
```

./run.ksh  - is script that has some business logic to send the data to other machine and waits for the response. Even if the response received it waits for reasonable amount of time to complete the processing. Because it waits for the connection to be closed and doing other cleanup activity.

My problem is that i want to kill that script after few seconds by sending ctrl+C. When i googled i found that $! can be used to get the process id of the background process, but the same cannot be used in this case.

Is it possible to send the ctrl+C in the shell script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use: `kill -SIGINT pid`

Comment: You need `pidof sleep`. Remember calling sleep, spawns a subshell for `sleep` its `PID` is separate and distinct from your script `PID`.

Comment: Since you are mixing `bash` and `ksh`, be aware that `sleep` is an external program when used from `bash`, but a shell builtin in `ksh` (so it does not create a sub-shell).

Comment: I need to kill "ksh ./run.ksh", as i mentioned earlier it needs the keyboard interaction and i cant run it in background. Is there are way to kill the ksh ./run.ksh command from the main script. I don't want anything to do with sleep as it a workaround i am using it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `timeout` command. For example it will be killed after 30 seconds.

```
timeout 30 ksh ./run.ksh
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The script run.ksh is not sending any data to the server. I would like to add it is a Seagull script to send the Diameter SH messages to server.